# Why flac file converted from mp4 weighs 4x than mp4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I did converted mp4 file to flac with

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 x.flac
```

x.mp4 weighs 11M and x.flac weighs 43M

Comment: You moved form a COMPRESSED (smaller) format to an uncompressed form and you are surprised that it became larger?

Comment: I like watching the -'s increase in real time on this one. However, technically, FLAC is *not* uncompressed, it's lossless compression. Which makes coming up with a 'duh' answer somewhat harder.

Answer (score 2):

Because the FLAC file has more data in it than the MP4 file.